# Testar uma condição antes de fazer UPDATE, com PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando o seguinte:
Preciso que o código abaixo primeiro verifique se o registro que está tentando ser finalizado (Passar de status 1 pra 2), já não esteja finalizado. Se não tiver segue o UPDATE NORMAL. Porém o que acontece é que quando tento finalizar um registro que já esta no banco com status 2 que é Finalizado, da a mensagem de que a não pode finalizar e tal, mas quando tento finalizar um registro que esta como ativo, que é status 1 no banco e que deveria então o UPDATE executar e passar pra 2, não aocontece nada. Obs: (Executando somente o UPDATE sem teste ele funciona normal).

```
<?php 
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(file_exists("../config.php")) {
    require "../config.php";        
} else {
    echo "Arquivo config.php nao foi encontrado";
    exit;
}


$id = $_GET["id"];
settype($id, "integer");

Abre_Conexao();
//status
if($id){

/*STATUS: 1 = ATIVO, 2 = FINALIZADO*/

$sqlstatus = "SELECT * FROM projetos WHERE STATUS_PROJETO = '2' AND COD_PROJETO = $id";
$resultadost = mysql_query($sqlstatus) or die(mysql_error());

while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultadost)) {
    if($linha['STATUS_PROJETO'] > '0')
    echo "Atividade já estava finalizada";

}
} else {
    mysql_query("UPDATE projetos SET status_projeto = '2' where cod_projeto = $id");
    mysql_close();
    header("Location: projetos.php");

}
?>
```

Comment: Esse if  `if($linha['STATUS_PROJETO'] > '0')` não deveria ser `if($linha['STATUS_PROJETO'] == 2)`. Existe `STATUS_PROJETO` com valor zero?

Comment: Realmente deveria ser assim, porém ajustei e agora retorna uma página em branco (Apenas com erro de conexão PDO, mas isso é por causa do metodo que usei). @rray

Comment: Mas vc não está usando o PDO.

Comment: Não. To com a conexão antiga, mas esse erro ta dando em outras páginas, não seria ele o problema.

Comment: Poderia atualizar o código da pergunta. Está um pouco confuso, olhe o `if($id){` quando cai no else supostamente não tem id nesse caso vc faz update, update com qual id? Quando for testar comente todos os `header(....);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que correto seria atualizar o projeto somente quando um id for encontrado e seu status seja `1`.

```
if($id){
    $sqlstatus = "SELECT * FROM projetos WHERE COD_PROJETO = $id";
    $resultadost = mysql_query($sqlstatus) or die(mysql_error());
    $projeto = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultadost));

    if($projeto['STATUS_PROJETO'] == '2')
        echo "Atividade já estava finalizada";
    } else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE projetos SET status_projeto = '2' where cod_projeto = $id")
        or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_close();
        //header("Location: projetos.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: @TiagoIB era isso mesmo?